# Unity missing after update 12.10

Tags: unity

After I downloaded and installed updates for 12.10 today I have no side bars/folders in unity.  Everything is missing except for my desktop background pic and the mouse cursor.  I can still bring up the terminal and have already tried:

`unity --reset`

This is meet with:

`ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated`

I have tried **CCSM** also to no avail.  When I try to enable/re-enable Ubuntu utility plugin I get an error message-box saying some bindings conflict with other plugins.

I have also tried reinstalling unity which did nothing as well.

I am about out of ideas.  Please help.

Comment: There are several options on [the mega-thread for this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) so I suggest you try some of the others. Deleting compiz configuration might be a good next step (or move it). Head down the list of answers and update your question to let us know how you get on.

Comment: I had similar problems after installing updates. Solved it by reinstalling proprietary amd display drivers.

Comment: I solved this by re-enabling Unity from CCSM. If you have binding conflicts, resolve them.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx lightdm  
sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop
```

Then restart your computer and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: did nothing for Ubuntu 14 LTS